# Missing POST parameter with jQuery AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have aproblem with a AJAX POST via jQuery. Here is the client code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/registration_and_login/login.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {saveConection: saveConection, loginEmail: loginEmail, loginPass: loginPass }
}).always(login);
```

And here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
include '../functions/connection.php';
$link = conenct('localhost', 'root', '', 'w_db');

$saveConection = $_POST['saveConection'];
$loginEmail = $_POST['loginEmail'];
$loginPass = $_POST['loginPass'];

$loginEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($loginEmail);
$loginPass = mysql_real_escape_string($loginPass);
$saveConection = mysql_real_escape_string($saveConection);

$emailResult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('id') FROM users WHERE userEmail = '$loginEmail' AND userPass = '$loginPass'") or die('Invalid query:'. mysql_error());
$validation = mysql_result($emailResult, 0);

if($validation) {
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userEmail = '$loginEmail'") or die('Invalid query:'. mysql_error());
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
    $id = $tmp['id'];

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

    if($saveConection == 'yes'){
        setcookie('login', $loginEmail);
        setcookie('password', $loginEmail);
    }
    echo "true";
}
else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

I am getting this error:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: saveConection in **C:...\login.php** on line **5**

It seems to me that there is no problem with the POST of `saveConection`, and I can't find the problem.

Comment: You realize you spelled 'connect' wrong, right?

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` and see what comes up.

Comment: This is likely a typo `$_POST['saveConection']` should be `$_POST['saveConnection']`  unless misspelled in your form too...

Comment: Is `saveConection` (if spelled that way) a checkbox? If it is, the post key _won't be present unless it is checked_. So if you submit it without checking the box, it will issue the notice. Instead check `if (isset($_POST['saveConection']))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for your post value you must check if they are existing before calling the page ...

so you must do :

```
if(isset($_POST['saveConection']))
   $saveConection = $_POST['saveConection'];

if(isset($_POST['loginEmail']))
   $loginEmail = $_POST['loginEmail'];

if(isset($_POST['loginPass']))
   $loginPass = $_POST['loginPass'];
```

i hope you understand !

Comment: I know that they are existing because I posted the via ajax call